Error during dual boot installation
￼​I am trying to dual boot windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04LTS on my ASU’s tuf f15 laptop. I want windows on my internal hardrive and Ubuntu on my external Toshiba hardrive.
I am faced with this error during install :
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/target/us/lib/modules/6.5.0-18-generic/kernel/net/tipc/tipc.ko'

So I went into live usb, I formatted the external hardrive to ext4 with gparted.
I created 4 partitions
/root - 100gb 
/swap - 16gb 
/home - 800gb 
/efi - 2000mb

I chose the same EFI as the install location for Ubuntu but I am now faced with this error,
Could the errror be because I formatted the hardrive to be Linux only maybe I should of done the ntfs one instead?
Or is it because I need to have the boot sequence on my internal hardrive and that’s why is coming up with the error?


Could the errror be because I formatted the hardrive to be Linux only maybe I should of done the ntfs one instead?

I would keep the hard drive to be what it was before, Linux should be able to handle NTFS drivers well especially Ubuntu. Make sure that the drive you mount has read/write access.
If not then try this to the root drive and CMIIW you don't need another EFI partition when dualbooting.:
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /target


Or is it because I need to have the boot sequence on my internal hard drive and that’s why is coming up with the error?

I am still learning too so instead I share you my personal experience with dual booting. When using Ubuntu 22.04LTS you can try do the following to ensure working partions:

Empty the partition you manually made.
Allow windows to extend the size again to ensure nothing is left behind.
Allocate the total amount of GB you want to set for Ubuntu and leave it empty
Using a USB Installer of Ubuntu and then when installing you should see install alongside windows option and you can just follow on the next steps in the installer, but if you wish to custom your partiton then using the installer's gparted to set as how you want and ensuring the correct usage/permission.

Hope this helps, Happy learning.
